# cant display img with text android

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with displaying img + text on listview. I have a code that works ok on simulator, but when I install my code on my Samsung Galaxy s, I can't see the pic near the text.
I don't know what the problem is, because on my simulator its work fine.
May be, because I don't have an SD card? How can I change my code that it will work ok on my device?
The code is:
on getView

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imgUrl, activity,  ImageView);

package rusNewsTest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import com.example.News.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

  public class ImageThreadLoader {

//the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with something      like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
/** The cache. */
private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

/** The cache dir. */
private File cacheDir;

/**
 * Instantiates a new image loader.
 *
 * @param context the context
 */
public ImageThreadLoader(Context context){
    //Make the background thead low priority. This way it will not affect the UI performance
    photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);

    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"cache_dir_img");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}
//This is used for a stub when the user can not see the actual image..
//this images will be seen
final int stub_id =R.drawable.stub;


/**
 * Display image.
 *
 * @param url the url
 * @param activity the activity
 * @param imageView the image view
 */
public void displayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
{
    if(cache.containsKey(url))
        imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }    
}

/**
 * Queue photo.
 *
 * @param url the url
 * @param activity the activity
 * @param imageView the image view
 */
private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
{
    //This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them. 
    photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
    PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
        photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
    }

    //start thread if it's not started yet
    if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
        photoLoaderThread.start();
}

/**
 * Gets the bitmap.
 *
 * @param url the url
 * @return the bitmap
 */
private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
{
    //I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the demo.
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

    //from SD cache
    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b!=null)
        return b;

    //from web
    try {
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        copyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Exception ex){
       ex.printStackTrace();
       return null;
    }
}

//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
/**
 * Decode file.
 *
 * @param f the f
 * @return the bitmap
 */
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}

//Task for the queue
/**
 * The Class PhotoToLoad.
 */
private class PhotoToLoad
{

    /** The url. */
    public String url;

    /** The image view. */
    public ImageView imageView;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new photo to load.
     *
     * @param u the u
     * @param i the i
     */
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
        url=u; 
        imageView=i;
    }
}

/** The photos queue. */
PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

/**
 * Stop thread.
 */
public void stopThread()
{
    photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
}

//stores list of photos to download
/**
 * The Class PhotosQueue.
 */
class PhotosQueue
{

    /** The photos to load. */
    private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

    //removes all instances of this ImageView
    /**
     * Clean.
     *
     * @param image the image
     */
    public void Clean(ImageView image)
    {
        for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
            if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                photosToLoad.remove(j);
            else
                ++j;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The Class PhotosLoader.
 */
class PhotosLoader extends Thread {

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Thread#run()
     */
    public void run() {
        try {
            while(true)
            {
                //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                    }
                if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                {
                    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                    synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                        photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                    }
                    Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                    cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                    if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                        BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                        Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                    }
                }
                if(Thread.interrupted())
                    break;
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            //allow thread to exit
        }
    }
}

/** The photo loader thread. */
PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

//Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
/**
 * The Class BitmapDisplayer.
 */
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{

    /** The bitmap. */
    Bitmap bitmap;

    /** The image view. */
    ImageView imageView;

    /**
     * Instantiates a new bitmap displayer.
     *
     * @param b the b
     * @param i the i
     */
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
     */
    public void run()
    {
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
          imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

/**
 * Clear cache.
 */
public void clearCache() {
    //clear memory cache
    cache.clear();

    //clear SD cache
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}

 public static void copyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }


    }
[/CODE]
```